# Why is elastic search raising MultiJson::ParseError?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I am adding the [elasticsearch gem](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-model) to an existing rails app hosted on Heroku.

Running `MyModel.import` in production is raising an error

```
MultiJson::ParseError: unexpected character at line 1, column 1 [parse.c:690]
```

As my development and test environments are working perfectly, I assume that this is being caused by the data in MyModel, perhaps an encoding issue. But as this table is quite large, I am having trouble tracking down the problem.

1. Can anyone confirm that this error is likely to be caused by an
   issue in the data being imported?
2. Is there a way to inspect the JSON data representation that `MyModel.import` invokes?

### EDIT

Following suggestions below, I have tried running a few commands to track down the error.

```
MyModel.all.each(&:as_json) 
MyModel.all.each(&:as_indexed_json) 
MyModel.all.each { |r| r.__elasticsearch__.as_indexed_json }
MyModel.all.each { |r| MultiJson.load r.to_json }
```

are all running without errors. However they do not appear to be returning json, but arrays of records. Is this usual?

```
[#<MyModel id: 1, ......
```

Running `import` on a limited number of records is also causing strange results.

```
# a single record returns no error
MyModel.import query: -> { where(id: 1) }  
=> 0
# multiple records return the error
MyModel.import query: -> { where(id: 1..2) }  
MultiJson::ParseError: unexpected character at line 1, column 1 [parse.c:690]
```

The full stack trace is

```
MultiJson::ParseError: unexpected character at line 1, column 1 [parse.c:690]
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/multi_json-1.11.3/lib/multi_json/adapters/oj.rb:15:in `load'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/multi_json-1.11.3/lib/multi_json/adapters/oj.rb:15:in `load'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/multi_json-1.11.3/lib/multi_json/adapter.rb:20:in `load'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/multi_json-1.11.3/lib/multi_json.rb:119:in `load'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-5.0.4/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/serializer/multi_json.rb:24:in `load'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-5.0.4/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:322:in `perform_request'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-5.0.4/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:20:in `perform_request'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-5.0.4/lib/elasticsearch/transport/client.rb:131:in `perform_request'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/elasticsearch-api-5.0.4/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/bulk.rb:95:in `bulk'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/elasticsearch-model-5.0.1/lib/elasticsearch/model/importing.rb:123:in `block in import'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/elasticsearch-model-5.0.1/lib/elasticsearch/model/adapters/active_record.rb:106:in `block in __find_in_batches'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:121:in `block in find_in_batches'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:214:in `block in in_batches'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:198:in `loop'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:198:in `in_batches'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:120:in `find_in_batches'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/elasticsearch-model-5.0.1/lib/elasticsearch/model/adapters/active_record.rb:105:in `__find_in_batches'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/elasticsearch-model-5.0.1/lib/elasticsearch/model/importing.rb:122:in `import'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/elasticsearch-model-5.0.1/lib/elasticsearch/model.rb:118:in `import'
    from (irb):14
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.6/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
```

This is proving to be a frustrating issue to debug. I am grateful for any further suggestions or ideas.

Comment: Try running 1) `MyModel.all.each(&:as_json)`  2) `MyModel.all.each(&:as_indexed_json)` 3) `MyModel.all.each { |r| r.__elasticsearch__.as_indexed_json }`    Are there any errors?

Comment: Thanks @chumakoff. I have run all 3 without any errors being raised. Now I am even more confused as to why MyModel.import is raising an error. Do you have any more suggestions that I can try to debug this?

Comment: Looks like the problem is with encoding. Does the model content have any strange symbols? ) Try to import a specific record like this: `MyModel.import query: -> { where(id: 1) }`    Also try running `MyModel.all.each { |r| MultiJson.load r.to_json  }`

Comment: Thanks @chamakoff, I appreciate your help. This issue is proving to be very mysterious! I have updated the question with some more details. I am grateful for any more suggestions.

Comment: I think the problem is with a specific record. Try to `import` each record individually and find the one (or the ones) that cause the error. Have you tried running code from my previous comment, that is `MyModel.all.each { |r| MultiJson.load r.to_json }`?